# Power automate send a survey out to customers that have been with the company for one month?

Tags: conditional-statements, power-automate

I am using power automate to send a survey to clients after one month of joining.

`formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -30), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

sort of thing, just the month is not exactly 30 or 31 days every time.

Any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formatDateTime(addToTime(utcNow(),-1,'Month'),'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: How is this easier?